# DRY up flip-flop operator

Tags: ruby, optimization, dry

Currently trying to dry up my flip-flop operator and I'm not sure of the best way to do it. Ideas?

```
@log_file = "07-07-14 to 07-13-14_debug.log"

def error_sort
  File.readlines(@log_file).each do |line|
    if (line =~ /<DEBUG>/ .. line =~ /<(?!DEBUG).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!DEBUG).+>/
      File.open("debug.txt", "a") << line
    elsif (line =~ /<INFO >/ .. line =~ /<(?!INFO ).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!INFO ).+>/
      File.open("info.txt", "a") << line
    elsif (line =~ /<WARN >/ .. line =~ /<(?!WARN ).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!WARN ).+>/
      File.open("warn.txt", "a") << line
    elsif (line =~ /<ERROR>/ .. line =~ /<(?!ERROR).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!ERROR).+>/
      File.open("error.txt", "a") << line
    elsif (line =~ /<FATAL>/ .. line =~ /<(?!FATAL).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!FATAL).+>/
      File.open("fatal.txt", "a") << line
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would starts with something like this:

```
LOGLEVELS = ['debug', 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'fatal']

def loglevel?(level, line)
  level = level.upcase
  (line =~ /<#{level}>/ .. line =~ /<(?!#{level}).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!#{level}).+>/
end

def error_sort
  File.readlines(@log_file).each do |line|
    LOGLEVES.each do |level| 
      File.open("#{level}.txt", "a") << line if loglevel?(level, line)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For efficiency, perhaps `if loglevel?(level,line); File.open(...) << line; break; end`.